# Why is スタイル used to denote body figure?

Tags: etymology

You know how Japanese people say "スタイルのいいお姉さん" to basically refer to "that girl with huge boobs" or "that really tall girl"? I've seen this get thrown around a lot but never really got the rationale behind this. My guess is that it's a euphemism but can someone give an accurate explanation of this?

Comment: Absolutely don't know that, and wouldn't assume that's what a native or strong speaker was a eluding to.  Tall?  Maybe, but that comes down to a bit of prejudice that taller girls are fashionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Japanese, スタイルのいい女性 is a plain and straightforward phrase that means "a woman with a nice figure/body." No euphemism is involved. And it usually refers to her general appearance, not specifically to her height or breast.

大辞泉 says [the primary meaning of スタイル is 姿 (*figure*) of a person](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/118595/m0u/), although it can also mean *manner*, *fashion*, *format*, etc. [Many Japanese people simply believe that definition](http://www.eigowithluke.com/2013/06/style/), and you can call it a kind of 和製英語.

I failed to find the exact explanation of when and why スタイル came to mean body figure, but I think the reason is easy to speculate. スタイル was already used in such a way at least in [a novel written in 1927](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000037/files/1417_22265.html).

> 少佐がどうして彼を従卒にしたか、それは、彼がスタイルのいい、好男子であったからであった。そのおかげで彼は打たれたことはなかった。しかし、彼は、なべて男が美しい女を好くように、上官が男前だけで従卒をきめ…